# Disruption Orb blocking mechanics

Tags: werewolv.es

In the online game of werewolv.es, if a player uses their night action to target someone holding the  Disruption Orb, they are blocked, but are they seen *visiting* the Orb-holder by other roles/runes, such as the Stalker/Harlot?

Whilst the outcome of the visit to an Orb-holder is a block to the visitor's night action, does the visit physically take place to be seen?